# Settling Multiple Azure Service Bus Messages on a Single Request using nodejs

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus

I am receiving messages from Azure Service Bus using  [@azure/service-bus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)

using something like this (simplified)

```
let receivingMode = ReceiveMode.peekLock;
let sbClient = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString);  
let subscriptionClient = this.sbClient.createSubscriptionClient(topicName, subscriptionName);
let receiver = this.subscriptionClient.createReceiver(receivingMode);
let messages = await this.receiver.receiveMessages(maxMessageCount, maxWaitTimeInSeconds);
```

It is possible that I'll get hundreds of messages per bulk and I saw that I can only complete() one by one, for example:

```
for (let index = 0; index < messages.length; index++) {
    let message = messages[index];
    await message.complete();
}
```

This seems that it will be a very slow process... is there a better approach?

Comment: If you are processing the multiple queues all the time, it might not need parallelisation on a single batch. ms provide some info on the async approaches in [their docco](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#settling-send-operations)

Answer (score 1):

Process your messages concurrently. As far as I understand, you should not receive new messages unless you have processed old ones.

```js
const promises = [];
for (let index = 0; index < messages.length; index++) {
    let message = messages[index];
    promises.push(settleMessage(message));
}
await Promise.all(promises);

async function settleMessage(message) {
  // process your message here
  // Use other methods (abandon(), deadLetter(), defer()) depending on processing result;
  // Otherwise, I suggest to use different receiving mode;
  await message.complete();
}
```

Comment: yea but it is ok to do it on hundreds simultaneously?

Comment: Don't see any issue here unless it hundreds of thousands. What are your concerns?

Comment: each one makes a request to the server. I am listening on ~10 different queues and some of them could be really big, maybe it's better to batch it? do 50 simultaneously and wait?

Comment: Might hit [azures throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-throttling)

Comment: bluebirds [promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) has a concurrency limit.  I'm guessing there's also a usefulness limit that will be quick to find... where there's no point scheduling any more at once.

Comment: Take a look at Matt's comment on the question - it looks like MS also suggests completing in batch, meaning if I have 500 messages and the batch is 50, I will wait 10 times for 50 messages to complete...

I am not sure though why there is no batch complete where there are multiple messages being settled...

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus does not support batch settlement of messages(as of now).

You can settle the messages one by one, you can follow the approach mentioned in the other answers where you'd `await` on all the outstanding promises to complete the messages.

Related issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/11914 that talks about the similar feature request and the reply from the service team.

Also, the code snippet in the question seems to be using the version 1 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK.

I'd recommend using the latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` that has been released recently.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)